# How to validate the form using angularjs when the name field has .(dot) in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my form I have a input tag with name="Customer.Firstname" so when i refer to name value in angularjs its taking only customer as the value and .Firstname is going unidentified.
Here is my code:

```
<label class="label_block" ng-hide="ApplicantDetails.Customer.FirstName.$error.required || ApplicantDetails.Customer.FirstName.$error.pattern">FirstName</label>
<span class="clearable">
    <input class="textbox"  type="text" name="Customer.FirstName" ng-model="Customer.FirstName" ng-init="Customer.FirstName='@Model.Customer.FirstName'" value="@Model.Customer.FirstName" ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z-']{1,30})$/" required="required"/>
</span>
```

Here am trying to hide the label when the textbox is empty.How can i do that?

Comment: You can give a different name than the ng-model. It could be CustomerFirstName. Or maybe use thé array notation like Form['Customer.FirstName']

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to access keys with dot

```
<label class="label_block" ng-hide="ApplicantDetails['Customer.FirstName'].$error.required || ApplicantDetails['Customer.FirstName'].$error.pattern">FirstName</label>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eCE7S/)

This can be rewritten as

```
<label class="label_block" ng-show="ApplicantDetails['Customer.FirstName'].$valid">FirstName</label>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aGXgm/)

Comment: What if we have brackets in the name of textbox name like `<input type= "text" name="Entries[0].Amount"/>` you can think of this textbox rendered by ng-repeat attribute on some html element that in turn have this textbox. how would bracket notation work in that case?

Comment: @Arun P Johny: I have a similar question, I asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146035/validating-form-using-angular-when-name-field-has-dots-and-brackets. please have a look.