# Validating form using Angular when name field has dots and brackets

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

The form to be validated is master detail i.e. it has two portions. master portion contains two fields while detail portion initially has two rows but they can be increased by pressing a button on DOM. The form looks like the following
[image]

The problem is that in detail portion I have to create the inputs using `ng-repeat` like

```
<div class="form-group">
          <table style="margin-left:10%;">
             <tr>
                <th>Account id</th>
                <th>Amount</th>

             </tr>
             <tr class="edit-row" ng-repeat ="entry in model.Entries">
                <td>

                   <input type="text" ng-model="model.Entries[$index].AccountId" required  name="Entries[{{$index}}].AccountId"/>


                </td>
                <td>
                   <input type="text" ng-model="model.Entries[$index].Amount" required name="Entries[{{$index}}].Amount"/> 
                   <span class="field-validation-error text-danger" ng-show="transactionForm['Entries['{{$index}}'].Amount'].$invalid && transactionForm['Entries['{{$index}}'].Amount'].$dirty">
                     Amount is Required
                   </span>
                </td>


             </tr>

          </table>

       </div>
```

But the `ng-show` attribute is not working fine for the detail portion. This is because, I have dots (.) and brackets ([) in the name of input fields. How can I perform validation in such scenario. Someone may argue to change the names of the input but I have to use this convention for input names in the detail portion. In current code, I have used bracket notation in `ng-show` attribute of Amount field as described in [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403239/how-to-validate-the-form-using-angularjs-when-the-name-field-has-dot-in-it), but to no avail. you can find complete example at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0iLqVBhlgKEAtnw2wJgI?p=preview)

Comment: or if there is a way to invoke validations on id field rather than name. I can generate ID's without dots and brackets

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
       ng-show="model.Entries[$index].Amount === ''"
```

Rather than trying to check the form value check the actual model value. This will work assuming you are just checking to make sure there is a value other than the empty string. You will have to make the check more specific to what you are looking for. You can also set the type="number" if you only want to allow the user to enter a numeric value.

Comment: basically this is a test case. I have to apply other validations like minlength, patter etc. as well

Comment: Then how about just making it a function call and do all your validation in that function.

Comment: Is there a way I can bind validations to Id attribute rather than name attribute. I can make the name attribute unique

Comment: how would a function then be able to change the state of a form field to $valid and not $valid?

Comment: Take a look at Custom Validation in the documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms